# Gaming performance issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, games, steam

After a month of using my new computer without major issues, I finally decided to install the Steam library in the system. Some slender games run properly but all the big guns in Clausewitz (Paradox) and Unity engines are almost frozen. The programs open and the game perform but at 1-2 FPS (not joking) so not workable situation. Any input in the possible problem?

Technical specs:
CPU: Ryazen 5 3600X
RAM: Crucial 16 (8*2) Gb 2666 Mhz
Motherboard: ASUS B450 plus TUF
GPU: MSI GeForce 1650 gaming (4Gb)
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Solved, I was running in Neuveau instead of the NDivia drivers.

Comment: Please post the details of your solution as an answer.